# Enable Intellij or Android Studio KDE Global Menu

Tags: kde, android-studio, intellij, globalmenu

I've been looking for this for a long time but still I can't get it work.

I tried using `Jayatana` and activate it in `idea.properties` like this:

```
-linux.native.menu=true 
-javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
```

And installing `appmenu-gtk-module`, `appmenu-gtk2-module`, `appmenu-gtk3-module` but it didn't work.

Did anyone make it work?!

System:

- KDE Neon Bionic Based
- Plasma 5.14.1
- Kernel 4.15.0-36-generic

Comment: I've been trying to find a solution myself. I'm running under Manjaro with Plasma 5.14.1. I came across [this bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-169904) on the JetBrains issue tracker from two years ago, asking for KDE Global Menu support in Ubuntu. It was last updated two weeks ago at the time of writing, and claims to be fixed, though many are still suffering from this issue.

Comment: I have the last version of intellij and still with no Global Menu. Did you made it work @Eamonn?

Comment: So it suppose to be fixed in build `183.3459`. Last stable build is `182.4892.20`. Finger crossed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**LAST UPDATE**

- Intellij version 2020.2.1 has been reported with issues in global menu, previous version worked out of the box

  [Intellij issue track link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-169904)
- Some hope for Android Studio, global menu is working in version 4.2 Canary10

  [Android Studio issue track link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121304907)

Comment: it workfs fine in my IntelliJ but not in WebStrom :(

Comment: Some people are writing in the ticket that in new version 2020.2.1 the global menu stop working https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-169904